# Google Games authentication between different developer accounts

Tags: node.js, authentication, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-games

We have a setup with multiple Unity games that authenticate with a single Node server. Our current system allows users to log in via Google Play across all our games. Thus, when a user logs into Game 1 and then Game 2 using Google Play, their identity remains consistent due to the persistent playerId that Google provides across multiple games.

However, we're now facing a challenge. We want to allow external games, which are created by a different developer account, to also connect to our server. The issue is that Google Play returns a different playerId for the same player in these cases.

Is there any method to link the two accounts in such a way that the playerId returned by Google Games remains consistent across all apps, regardless of the developer account they originate from?

This is what I currently have , based on each game I extract the client and secret server side

and get the playerId , now in the case of google returning a different playerId for the same player it will break

```
  const { code, gameId } = req.query;

  if (!code) {
    throw new BadRequestError('code is required in query params');
  }
  if (!gameId) {
    throw new BadRequestError('gameId is required in query params');
  }
  const googlePlayJson = JSON.parse(
    process.env.GOOGLE_PLAY_JSON
  ) as GooglePlayJson;
  if (!googlePlayJson) {
    throw new NotFoundError(
      'googlePlayJson not found please contact backend dev'
    );
  }
  //based on gameId get the correct client id and secret from the array
  const json = googlePlayJson.find((game) => game.gameId === gameId);
  if (!json) {
    throw new NotFoundError(
      `gameId ${gameId} not found in env json please contact backend dev`
    );
  }

  const oauth2Client = new OAuth2Client({
    clientId: json.clientId,
    clientSecret: json.clientSecret
  });

  const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken({
    code: req.query.code as string
  });

  oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
  const games = google.games({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: oauth2Client
  });

  const response = await games.players.get({
    playerId: 'me',
    language: 'en'
  });

  const playerId = response.data.playerId;
  if (!playerId) {
    throw new NotFoundError('playerId not found');
  }
  const displayName = response.data.displayName;
  let user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: { playerId }
  });
  if (!user) {
    user = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        playerId,
        name: displayName
      }
    });
```